# Using Linkify in ListView's ArrayAdapter causes RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, linkify

I have a `TextView` in my `ArrayAdapter` that may contain some hyperlinks. For those links I  use `Linkify`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.content = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.postContent);
        holder.date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.postDate);

        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.content.setText(contents.get(position));
    holder.date.setText(dates.get(position));

    Linkify.addLinks(holder.content, Linkify.ALL);

    return rowView;
}
```

But because the `Linkify` is added in the ArrayAdapter, I get an exception saying this:

```
08-05 16:42:16.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 16:42:16.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20598): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-05 16:42:16.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20598):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:921)
08-05 16:42:16.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20598):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:283)
08-05 16:42:16.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20598):    at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
```

How can I make this work? I can't think of an alternative.

Comment: Are you sure that's all you're finding in the logcat? It looks to me like there are a few more exceptions following which could contain valuable information.

Comment: Nope, it's about running an activity outside an activity context (the ArrayAdapter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the exception in the log, it seems that you used the application context when you allocate your `ArrayAdapter`. For example, if your code looks similar to the following:

```
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            data) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

You must have initialized the **context** variable above with the application context, like this:

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

To avoid the error, you should have initialized it with your `Activity` instance instead:

```
    Context context = this;
```

Or, if your code is in a `Fragment`:

```
    Context context = getActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to open a link, you can use

```
String text = "<a href=\"http://www.google.co.in/\">Google</a>";
holder.content.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
holder.content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

this would would work fine for you inside a ListView.

Comment: But you can't run other activities (the browser) outside an activity context. Linkify makes the URLs clickable that opens up the browser. This would still cause the exception. I somehow have to Linkify my `content` using activity context. If this is possible, could you explain why this WOULD work? I would like to know.

Comment: I had tried this is my app and it works fine inside non-Activity(Adapter) class too.

Comment: I'll be home in an hour, will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. I don't have HTML code in it, but they're just text starting with "http://" and "www.". Your method is looking for `HTML anchors <a>`.

Comment: thats what I am saying apply HTML to your text(link) and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity.Java while binding your list with adapter

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(YourCurrentActivityName.this, YourArrayList);
yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

In YourAdapter.java in Constructor make sure it's Activity not Context

```
public YourAdapter(Activity context, YourArrayList list){
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
```

And, use this code for your textview in your adapter for Linkify.

```
holder.yourTextView.setLinksClickable(true);
holder.yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
Linkify.addLinks(holder.yourTextView, Linkify.ALL);
holder.yourTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
```